# How can I merge two hard drives on an external linux server, without losing data already uploaded to one?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, storage

I have a media server running Plex over on Hetzner, but am in no way a server pro.

I failed to realise that my two 2.0TB hard drives would be completely separate, so instead of 4.0TB of space in my main /home directory it's capped itself at 1.8 (which I only realised after uploading 1.8TB of data...)

Running df -h I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G   13M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/md2        1.8T  1.7T  4.4G 100% /
tmpfs            16G  8.0K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        488M  183M  280M  40% /boot
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

And df /home tells me:

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2       1905568740 1805456300   3292060 100% /
```

So my home folder is stored on md2, which is saying it's full.

But according to fdisk -l, I have another 1.8TB available on sdb:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8c0aea5f

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048   33556479   33554432   16G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       33556480   34605055    1048576  512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       34605056 3907027119 3872422064  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9612d2cc

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048   33556479   33554432   16G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       33556480   34605055    1048576  512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       34605056 3907027119 3872422064  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/md1: 511.4 MiB, 536281088 bytes, 1047424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 1.8 TiB, 1982545854464 bytes, 3872159872 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md0: 16 GiB, 17163091968 bytes, 33521664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I've looked at walkthroughs on how to install LVM, as a possible method of creating a "combined drive" volume, but it's completely over my head.

Can anyone help me with a "for dummies" step-by-step guide on how to merge the two drives, so I can utilise the full 4.0TB for my /home directory? Preferably without losing the 1.8TB of data I've already uploaded there!

**Revision:**

mdadm --examine returns "mdadm: No devices to examine"

lsblk results:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdb       8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb2    8:18   0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sdb3    8:19   0   1.8T  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /
└─sdb1    8:17   0    16G  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0    16G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
sda       8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda2    8:2    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sda3    8:3    0   1.8T  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /
└─sda1    8:1    0    16G  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0    16G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
```

and cat /proc/mdstat:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      16760832 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      1936079936 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 1/15 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: your disk are in raid configuration I think you might not be able to do what you want

Comment: @Kiwy Damn... Is it possible to change the configuration at all? Would that mean starting from scratch and combining the disks somehow before I start uploading anything?

Comment: Can't tell I never configured Raid on linux, it depend if it's software or hardware raid. I can't tell you.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `mdadm --examine` as well as the output of `lsblk` to your question?  This'll help us understand if the disks are in RAID array config or not currently.

Comment: @ThomasWard - Outputs added! :)

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, you have a RAID system, running RAID1 (which is a mirror). If so, you don't actually have 1.8TB available, it is being used in the mirror. I'm not an Ubuntu person, but you might be able to do `cat /proc/mdstat`. It will show the active RAID and paritions.

Comment: @JonWatson So let me ask you for clarification: what *exactly* do you want to do here?  "Combine" the space across both disks to have 3.6TB of space instead of 1.8TB?

Comment: @KevinO - cat /proc/mdstat results have been added above! Hopefully that clears things up for you. I'm fairly certain it's alien, myself! :P

Comment: @ThomasWard - Exactly right. I want all 3.6TB to be available for me to use in my /home directory. Rather than 1.8TB there and 1.8TB elsewhere, which would require me to split my libraries and tell Plex to look in different places for different things, making it a nightmare to manage.

I just want one big volume of 3.6TB for me to use, rather than two 1.8s.

Comment: @JonWatson, though you have 2 1.8TB drives, they are bound in a RAID-1 mirror. Such a mirror provides some hardware redundancy, but at a 50% disk space cost. To make the change you want will require breaking the current RAID array, and there are potential issues with that. There is potentially a process, but it is difficult and not without risk. It would be easier to purchase an external back-up drive, copy the existing data to it, and then redo the entire setup. Some [discussion of moving RAID levels](https://serverfault.com/questions/737787/linux-convert-2-disk-raid1-to-raid0).

Comment: @KevinO - Damn... Okay, assuming I redo the entire setup, what's the best way to go about it? Is RAID0 the way to go? Or is LVM the better option? Once the server is reset and Ubuntu is reinstalled (Hetzner performs its own installation of Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS minimal), what exactly would I need to do?

Comment: Appreciate your insight on this, guys. Thank you very much for your help, pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: @JonWatson RAID0 will give you the space needs you need, as you said in your answer.  (I was going to post this as an answer, but you beat us all to it...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: Apparently it wasn't possible to combine drives without erasing everything and starting from scratch, so I started the Hetzner server in Rescue mode and followed the walkthrough here to setup Raid0 and LVM:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cf7g-qDoUho

From there I reinstalled Plex and started uploading everything from scratch...